# Writing to registry via Powershell problem

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write some value to the registry in remote computer and there is a weird problem...
This command works fine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC[0] {Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\XXX\YYY" -Name "Version" -Value "10"}
```

But if I replace a value by variable (like below), registry item is empty...

```
$version="10"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC[0] {Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\XXX\YYY" -Name "Version" -Value $version}
```

Do you know, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`-ArgumentList` to supply the values of parameters to the scriptblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#parameters)

```
$version = "10"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC[0] {
    param ($version)
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\XXX\YYY" -Name "Version" -Value $version 
} -ArgumentList $version
```

See also

- [Use Param keyword in a script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-11-use-the-param-keyword-in-a-script-block)
- [Use the $args automatic variable in a script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-12-use-the-args-automatic-variable-in-a-script-block)